# CSS : Background opacity is showing on text

Tags: html, css, opacity

Take this Code for example

```css
#backgroundimage {
  background: url("https://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/640x480/640x480-aero-solid-color-background.jpg");
  height: 50px
}

#container {
  background-color: #4C4C4C;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#text {
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="backgroundimage">
  <div id="container">
    <p id="text">
      Some text here
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to make the text color white while keeping the background image and container opacity intact.
[image: Look at this image as Reference]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the following example. Instead of `opacity` use `rgba`. 
According to [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity):

> opacity applies to the element as a whole, including its contents, even though the value is not inherited by child elements. Thus, the element and its children all have the same opacity relative to the element's background, even if they have different opacities relative to one another.

```css
#backgroundimage {
  background: url("https://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/640x480/640x480-aero-solid-color-background.jpg");
  height: 500px
}

#container {
  background-color: rgba(76,76,76,.5);
}

#text {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div id="backgroundimage">
  <div id="container">
    <p id="text">
      Some text here
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it help a Lot

Comment: Your code uses rgb instead of rgba.

Comment: this is the correct answer to your question, don't forget to close the question and pick this as the right answer

Comment: why flagging as duplicate then answering?

Comment: @TemaniAfif According to timestamp the answer came before the flag

Comment: you should then remove it .. it doesn't make sense to flag after answering IMHO .. and the timestamp show my close vote not yours

Comment: @connexo fixed it

Answer (score 0):

When you set the `opacity` of an element, it affects its children (and if you set an `opacity` of a child, it can't override the `opacity` of the parent.

What you need to do is not to set the `opacity` of the element, but set opacity only to the background - using `rgba`.

```css
#backgroundimage {
  background: url("https://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/640x480/640x480-aero-solid-color-background.jpg");
  height: 500px
}

#container {
  background-color: rgba(76, 76, 76, 0.5); /* #4C4C4C;*/
  /*opacity: 0.5;*/
}

#text {
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="backgroundimage">
  <div id="container">
    <p id="text">
      Some text here
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Make the background image (640x480-aero-solid-color-background.jpg) transparent and save it as .png or .gif format.

remove "opacity: 0.5" from "#container" class and "opacity: 1" from "#text" class